# Instruct PHP To Ignore Scanning A Folder

Tags: php, sitemap, dir

I've been working with a handy php script, which scans my site and spits out links to all the pages it finds. The problem is, it's also scanning my 'includes' folder, which contains all my .inc.php files.

Obviously I'd rather it ignore this folder when scanning the site, but for the life of me I can't see how to edit the script to tell it to do so.

The script is:

```
<?php 
// starting directory. Dot means current directory
$basedir = ".";

// function to count depth of directory 
function getdepth($fn){
return (($p = strpos($fn, "/")) === false) ? 0 : (1 + getdepth(substr($fn, $p+1)));
}

// function to print a line of html for the indented hyperlink
function printlink($fn){
  $indent = getdepth($fn); // get indent value
  echo "<li class=\"$indent\"><a href=\"$fn\">"; //print url
$handle = fopen($fn, "r"); //open web page file
$filestr = fread($handle, 1024); //read top part of html
fclose($handle); //clos web page file
if (preg_match("/<title>.+<\/title>/i",$filestr,$title)) { //get page title
    echo substr($title[0], 7, strpos($title[0], '/')-8); //print title
} else {
    echo "No title";
}
  echo "</a></li><br>\n"; //finish html
}

// main function that scans the directory tree for web pages 
function listdir($basedir){
if ($handle = @opendir($basedir)) { 
    while (false !== ($fn = readdir($handle))){ 
        if ($fn != '.' && $fn != '..'){ // ignore these
            $dir = $basedir."/".$fn; 
            if (is_dir($dir)){ 
                listdir($dir); // recursive call to this function
            } else { //only consider .html etc. files
                if (preg_match("/[^.\/].+\.(htm|html|php)$/",$dir,$fname)) {
                   printlink($fname[0]); //generate the html code
                }
                            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
    } 
} 
// function call 
listdir($basedir); //this line starts the ball rolling
?>
```

Now I can see where the script is told to ignore certain files, and I've tried appending:

```
&& $dir != 'includes'
```

...to it in numerous places, but my php knowledge is simply too shaky to know exactly how to integrate that code into the script.

If anyone can help, then you'd be saving me an awfully large headache. Cheers.

Comment: You really should look at something like RecursiveDirectoryIterator for things like this, so much cleaner http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php Few better options here too (forrst membership needed) http://forrst.com/posts/PHP_listing_files_in_a_directory-hvb

Comment: Thanks for that. My PHP is pretty shaky at present, so I just needed something that was quick and easy for now, but I'll certainly investigate the links you've added, and hopefully iterate with better code as I learn more. I appreciate the assistance though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it this line:

```
if ($fn != '.' && $fn != '..'){ // ignore these
```

so it's

```
if ($fn != '.' && $fn != '..' && $fn != 'includes'){ // ignore these
```

Comment: This will prevent any folder named 'includes' from your output. If you use this solution, remember to document this behavior.

Comment: This worked nicely, thanks a lot. Also, Floyd, thanks a lot for your input too, I wish I could give both answers a tick.

Answer (score 1):

Your path needs to be absolute. Add it at the top of listdir

```
function listdir($basedir){
    if($basedir == '/path/to/includes') {
         return;
    } [...]
```

This also makes sure that only one includes folder will be ignored.